# How do I populate one column in a MySQL table with values without getting "Not all parameters were used" programming error?

Tags: mysql, python-3.x

Here's the python 3 code I used:

```
import mysql.connector

mydb = mysql.connector.connect(
    host="localhost",
    user="username",        #I inserted the actual username here.
    passwd="password",      #I inserted the actual password here.
    database="mydatabase"
)

mycursor = mydb.cursor()
 #degrees is the table name, degreename is the column name. 
 #There are a total of two columns in the table, one for the id with should auto-increment, and the 'degreename' column that I'm trying to populate.

sql = "INSERT INTO degrees (degreename) VALUES (%s)" 
val = [
    ('Pharmacy'),
    ('Comp Sci'),
    ('Art'),
    ('History'),
    ('Psychology'),
    ('Medicine'),
    ('Sports'),
    ('Pottery')
]
mycursor.executemany(sql,val)
mydb.commit()
```

And here's the error I got:

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "newest.py", line 45, in <module>
    mycursor.executemany(sql,val)
  File "/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/3.8/lib/python3.8/site-packages/mysql/connector/cursor.py", line 668, in executemany
stmt = self._batch_insert(operation, seq_params)
  File "/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/3.8/lib/python3.8/site-packages/mysql/connector/cursor.py", line 613, in _batch_insert
raise errors.ProgrammingError(
mysql.connector.errors.ProgrammingError: Not all parameters were used in the SQL statement
```

What parameter am I missing in writing the SQL statement (or any other mistake(s) I've made that lead to this error)?
Thank you.

Comment: Your tuples need a comma in them to make them into tuples. Try `val = [
    ('Pharmacy',),
    ('Comp Sci',), ...`

Comment: @Nick that worked. Thank you :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your tuples need a comma in them to make them into tuples (see the [MySQL connector manual](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/connector-python/en/connector-python-api-mysqlcursor-executemany.html)). This will work:

```
val = [
    ('Pharmacy',),
    ('Comp Sci',),
    ('Art',),
    ('History',),
    ('Psychology',),
    ('Medicine',),
    ('Sports',),
    ('Pottery',)
]
```